# Handle Callback Exceptions In Another Method

Tags: java, exception, callback

I am connecting to a database and I want to make queries using callbacks, so I wrote this:

```java
public void query(String query, Consumer<ResultSet> callback, String database) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection;
    
    try { Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS); } 
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL + "/" + database, USER, "");
    
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    
    callback.accept(resultSet);
    
    connection.close();
}

public void printUsernames() throws SQLException {
    query("SELECT username FROM users;", (ResultSet set) -> {
            while (set.next()) {
                String username = set.getString("username");
                System.out.println(username);
            }           
    }, "cloud");
}
```

Even tough the `query` and `printUsernames` methods
both declare a throws statement, the Consumer I'm passing
in `printUsernames` still gives compiling errors (I'm warned I'm not handling its possible sql exceptions).

Is there a way to handle the Consumer exceptions within
`query` so that I don't have to write a try-catch over and over for any other queries?

Comment: What _precisely_ is the error you get?

Comment: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at main.ConnectDB.main(ConnectDB.java:41)**

In the main method I'm just creating a new ConnectDB and calling `printUsernames` inside a try-catch.

Comment: Is there an error message that specifically says this has to do with uncaught SQL exceptions?

Comment: Yes; my editor is highlighting `set.next` and `set.getString` (within `printUsernames`) notifying me of **Unhandled exception type SQLException**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can add a **throws** statement in the methods of an interface, so I wrote this:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Querier {
    public void query(ResultSet res) throws SQLException;
}
```

If I refactor my previous code a little...

```java
public void query(String query, Querier callback, String database) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection;
    
    try { Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS); } 
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL + "/" + database, USER, "");
    
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    
    callback.query(resultSet);
    
    connection.close();
}

public void printUsernames() throws SQLException {
    query("SELECT username FROM users;", (ResultSet set) -> {
        while (set.next()) {
            String username = set.getString("username");
            System.out.println(username);
        }
    }, "cloud");
}
```

Now I don't get any errors.